# I want a hidden form element to appear when a SPECIFIC radio button is checked?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, hidden

I can't seem to find a way of doing this, I can get it work off of the neares radio button to it, but not a specific one.

Here's my bit of code that almost does what I need it to:

```
...
Are you a supplier?:<br />
<input type="radio" name="supplier" id="supplier_no" value="0"/> No<br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="supplier" id="supplier_yes" value="1"/> Yes
<br /><br />
<div class="languagereveal1">
What Language do you work with?:<br />
<select name="language1" value="">
...
```

And the CSS supporting it:

```
.languagereveal1 {
opacity: 0;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .languagereveal1 {
opacity: 1;
max-height: 100px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

What I want, is the "Yes" radio button before the "No" radio button.

I figure there must be a way to specify using ID in that "input[type="radio"]" bit of the CSS, I've tried using what I know but that doesn't seem to be correct and I've looked around but cannot find anything.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move "Yes" button before "No", then with your HTML structure selector will be:

```css
#supplier_yes:checked ~ div > .languagereveal1 {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Or `input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div > .languagereveal1` will also work.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v3p2fju7/

Comment: Hi thanks for that!

I'll have to remember that's how to specify by ID in CSS.

May I ask, why is the <div> between yes and no needed and what is the div > meaning in the CSS?

Comment: You need `div` between because `~` is sibling selector it matches horizontally. So `input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .languagereveal1` means "get" same level sibling going after checked radio button. You don't have such sibling because `.languagereveal1` is inside a `div`. However radio button has div sibling which has direct child (`>` selctor) `.languagereveal1`.